# Using FOREACH_COUNTER within ForEach Mediator

Tags: wso2-esb

Having no luck trying to access the FOREACH_COUNTER value within a ForEach Mediator as indicated in the specification [ForEach Mediator Doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ForEach+Mediator)

I am trying to get the counter of the loop currently being performed and use that count in the sequence being executed.

Has anybody been able to retrieve the property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of properties FOREACH_COUNTER and FOREACH_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE also should be prefixed by ForEach ID and underscore. For example:

```
<foreach expression="//inline/a" id="Loop">
    <sequence>
        <log>
            <property expression="get-property('Loop_FOREACH_COUNTER')" name="Step"/>
            <property expression="get-property('Loop_FOREACH_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE')" name="Body"/>
        </log>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```

If you want to use this properties without prefixes you should check that `foreach` attribute `id` is absent. If it's present and empty you should use underscore prefix.